# Can you create Google Forms from Google Docs in an application?

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-docs, google-forms, google-docs-api

I am thinking about app that will use google form and I need to create forms from that app. Is there a way how can I create form in google docs without using website but through some api or some other way?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry, the API doesn't support programmatically creating forms.

Comment: Things have changed, a [Google Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/) for programming forms became available in early 2013.

Answer (score 1):

I can offer an idea for a solution using Google App Script.

Since the beginning of 2013 you can create new forms using the App Script [Forms Service API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/) quite easily.

```
var form = FormApp.create(title)
  .setDescription(description)
  .setConfirmationMessage('Thanks for responding!')
;
```

The problem now is how to get that App Script running from your non App Script code.

You can use App Script to create a [Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_web_apps) that reacts to HTTP GET requests.

So putting it together, you may be able to create an App Script Web App that reacts to a GET request and when it gets the right URL parameters, it creates the form.

Answer (score 1):

**(Nov 2020)** Yes, it is possible to [programmatically create Google Forms](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/06/auto-generating-google-forms.html). You can do it with [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) using its [Forms service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms). You can also extend the code to read in the contents from Google Docs (with Apps Script's [Document service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document)) and use it for the creation of Google Forms.

I created a [Google Workspace (formerly G Suite) Add-on](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons), which you can think of as a Google Docs extension, called [GFormIt](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/gformit_for_docs/183004038754). Its original purpose was intended for teachers to write exams/quizzes, possibly with answers, in Google Docs, then automatically convert them to Google Forms to distribute to students who submit their answers into Google Sheets (the destination for Google Forms submissions).

Furthermore, if you (the teacher) provided answers to your test questions, GFormIt would also auto-submit your answers to the Sheet as if you were a student. If you do **that**, and use a tool like [Flubaroo](http://flubaroo.com/) to grade the exam, you could designate your row in the Sheet as “the answer key.” You can learn more about how it works, including viewing a short video, at the GFormIt page linked above.

This [Google Docs add-on](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/editors/docs), along with others for Google Docs, Sheets, Slides, Forms, etc., are all certified/validated by Google and available for free to anyone from the [Google Workspace Marketplace](http://gsuite.google.com/marketplace). (However, your admins may have to grant permissions for you to try to install them to your corporate Workspace account.) If interested in building your own add-on, please see the [developer documentation](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/building-gsuite-addons) and perhaps some of [my introductory videos](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/videos) to get started, the most relevant being the one linked to at the top of this answer.

Apps Script is a serverless Google technology, meaning you write your code (using JavaScript) in the browser, and it is hosted by & executed on Google servers. If you wanted to create your own web app (and hosted anywhere), you would have to wait for a Google Forms REST API which does not exist at the time of this writing. (If we ever launch one, you'll find its documentation at https://developers.google.com/forms along with the others like Sheets https://developers.google.com/sheets, Gmail https://developers.google.com/gmail, Drive https://developers.google.com/drive, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Earlier this year (Mar 2022) the new Google Forms Api graduated from Beta. It is more powerful that the previous versions and caters for two main use cases:

- **Automated form creation and editing:** Enables automated form creation
  and editing. Enables rapid form generation from large volume question
  banks or other data backends.
- **Reaction to Form responses:** The API also enables developers to build
  automations for acting on incoming responses. Examples include
  developing real-time dashboards or visualizations and triggering
  business workflows based on response data.

We have used it to build an integration that Creates documents and slides each time a form is completed: [www.portant.co/google-forms-to-docs](https://www.portant.co/google-forms-to-docs) and it works really well.
I think the other key use case looks like it would be a good fit for you and others looking for a solution like this.
Cheers, James

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31961126)